# Cómo averiguar el aniversario de un usuario en la base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy buscando la manera de encontrar con SQL las personas que cumplirán un año en base a los registros que tengo en la base de datos.

Un decir.. tengo una persona que entró a trabajar el dia 29/03/2016
lo que quisiera saber es en base a ese registro obtener la fecha de hoy y teniendo un intervalo de días por ej. 30 días, la fecha de hoy y quiero encontrar los registros de los proximos 30 dias futuros.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Hola Fernando, ¿puedes ser un más claro, **ayudarte a qué**?

Comment: Y faltan muchos detalles importantes en tu pregunta: la estructura de tus tablas, coluimnas, ejemplos de  datos, etc...

Comment: Alguna vez haz hecho triggers? Creo que puedes realizar lo que comentas con un enfoque de eventos como los triggers o si por ejemplo estás con java o algún lenguaje de programación puedes implementar un ejb timer que ejecute tu función cada x tiempo de manera automática

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo  lo podria hacer de esta forma:

- Primero le sumo 1 año a su fecha de registro, esto para saber la fecha exacta de cuando cumplirá 1 año después de su registro...

Fecha de creación:  2016-06-15

Cumplirá 1 año: 2017-06-15

Código:

```
DATE_ADD(fecha_creacion, INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

- Ahora obtengo la fecha actual, y le sumo 30 días.

Código:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Y ahora la condición sería:

Si su fecha de creación más 1 año:  **2017-06-15**

Se encuentra entre la fecha actual: **2017-03-15**

Y la fecha actual mas 30 días: **2017-04-01**

Entonces devuelve los resultados.

Ejemplo de código completo:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios  WHERE  DATE_ADD('FECHA_REGISTRO'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) BETWEEN  CURDATE() AND  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta anterior usa unas funciones que son de MySql. Tengo entendido que usted pregunta por Sql Server.

En Sql Server la funcion que agrega intervalos de tiempo a la fecha especificada es DATEADD(), Por ejemplo:

select dateadd(Year,1,'29/03/2016');
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**select dateadd(day,3,'1980/11/02');**

retorna "1980/11/05", agrega 3 días.

**select dateadd(month,3,'1980/11/02');**

retorna "1981/02/02", agrega 3 meses.

La función que obtiene la fecha actual es: 
**getdate()**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El ejemplo del código adaptado en versión Sql Server seria algo como esto:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios  WHERE  DATEADD(Year,1,FECHA_REGISTRO) BETWEEN  getdate() AND  DATEADD(Day,30,getdate());
```

Sugiero que mire este enlace, puede serle muy util:
[Funciones para el uso de fechas Sql Server](http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/sqlserverya/temarios/descripcion.php?cod=33&punto=&inicio=)